# Error in calculating speed using thread in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, multithreading

```
package project.vtrac.tracker;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

public class MapView extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

    GoogleMap googleMap;
    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;
    private Double speed;
    private int curTime;
    private int lastTime;
    private Double lastLat;
    private Double lastLng;
    TextView msgArea;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapview);

        checkGooglePlayService();
    }

    public void checkGooglePlayService()
    {
        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        // Showing status
        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) // Google Play Services are not available
        { 
            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        }
        else 
        {
            createMap();
        }
    }

    public void createMap()
    {
        // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of map.xml
        SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
        googleMap = mapFrag.getMap();

        // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

        //Start location manager to start location updates
        startLocationUpdate();      
    }

    public void startLocationUpdate()
    {
        // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Getting the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Getting Current Location
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if(location!=null){
            lastLat = location.getLatitude();
            lastLng = location.getLongitude();
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 5000, 10, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        // Getting latitude of the current location
        latitude = location.getLatitude();

        // Getting longitude of the current location
        longitude = location.getLongitude();

        //get the current date time in reference to milliseconds from location.getTime()
        Date curDate = new Date(location.getTime());

        Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(); // creates a new calendar instance
        calendar.setTime(curDate);    //assign calender to given date

        //convert time to seconds
        curTime =  (int) ((calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)*60 + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE))*60 + calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));

        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        // Showing the current location in Google Map
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16));
        msgArea = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_msgArea);

        String msg;
        msg = "\tLatLong:" + latitude + "," + longitude+
                "\tLatLong:" + lastLat + "," + lastLng+
                "\t Speed:"+speed;
        msgArea.setText(msg);

      //calculateSpeed
        calculateSpeedThread();  
        lastTime = curTime;
        lastLat = latitude;
        lastLng = longitude;
    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    } 



    public void calculateSpeedThread()
    {
        Thread sThread = new Thread(null, doCalculateSpeed, "Speed Calculator");
        sThread.start();
    }

    private Runnable doCalculateSpeed = new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            speed = calculateSpeed();
        }
    };

    public double calculateSpeed()
    {
        double R = 6371.00; // km
        double lat1 = lastLat * (Math.PI/180);
        double lat2 = latitude * (Math.PI/180);
        double lng1 = lastLng * (Math.PI/180);
        double lng2 = longitude * (Math.PI/180);
        double dLat = (lat2-lat1);
        double dLon = (lng2-lng1);

        double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2); 
        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
        double distance = R*c;
        double timeDiff = (double)(curTime-lastTime);

        //speed in km/hr
        return ((distance/timeDiff) * 60 * 60); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }}
```

My speed is returning null. I want some help with this!
Speed is fine without using thread but when I use thread to reduce function overhead call time, I need to use thread to calculate speed.

Is it problem with my thread programming or what?

Comment: What do you mean by Speed here?

Comment: not sure why you want to do that in a thread? there are no loops/recur and you may not save much as there is some time spent in creating thread

Comment: I want to calculate speed of the device movement as the location of the device is changed and I also need to update those values into remote server. I have tried calculating speed with the same function mentioned above without thread and works fine but it takes more time to update when location is changed. So, I need to use thread to calculate speed for fast processing.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you want but I found an error in your code. You are passing **null** as the first parameter while creating thread. Try not to use that. I think you can use, 
**MapView.this** instead

Comment: The error you have received  was due to the username variable, Sorry for that but now  have edited that and there is no error.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the code above and there is no error but no values are null I suppose in the code above before passing to thread.

Comment: When I use the calculateSpeed() method instead of calculateSpeedThread() that is without thread. It works fine but while using thread both latitude and lastLat value appears to be same inside thread. Similarly, longitude/lastLng and curTime/lastTime appears to be same. So, it always returns NaN.